# Dragdealer.js is not working in hide/show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I put the drag Dealer in a div that is hidden by css (display:none), then when i show the div through jquery (.show()) the div shows the slider but it doesnt Drag.

No error in de firebug console.

any ideas?

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dragdealer.js"></script>
new Dragdealer('demo-simple-slider');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hide">
    <div class="size-bar" id="demo-simple-slider"><div class="dragable-bar handle"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can i get code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Help but I git the solution when I hide the element-container div by using

Jquery:

```
$(this).hide();
```

instead of

CSS:

```
display: none;
```